# How to copy files with window remote desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, clipboard, file-transfer, rds

I can do clipboard copy inside RDS client and then I can do paste on local computer. This will initiate copy process via RDS. Normal copy dialog with flying papers will appear.

Is it possible to initiate copy directly having source and destination paths?

Comment: Re: *"window remote desktop"*. Do you mean *"Windows remote desktop"*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Absolutely! What I do is enable **Local Drive Access** then use `robocopy`*`source`*`\\tsclient\shared_folder`. You can also use a different UNC path if it's on the same network as the system you are connecting to.

To view the shared folders you can access on the client computer (the one running the Remote Desktop Client), you can type `NET VIEW \\TSCLIENT` at the command prompt

Answer (score 4):

You can setup your RDP Client to automatically map local drives which will have your local drives show up in the remote session.

Comment: Could you say how? Let's say I connect to a computer on RDP (I have its IP). How can I map its D Drive to my computer?

Comment: On the first screen of the remote desktop GUI, click "Show Options" then go to the tab "Local Resources" then click "More" at the bottom. Expand Drives and then select the drives you want to connect. On the file explorer in Remote Desktop after you are connected they will show up under This PC as (for example) "D on MyComputerName"